# getc(stdin) seems to be tampering with the heap

Tags: c, memory-management

EDIT: Sorry for not providing an MCVE. I've created one here - http://pastebin.com/qxzPkfBW. Posted in full at the end of the question.

I'm writing a boolean logic parser/evaluator to learn some C. There is a lexical analyser that parses the input into a stream of token structs. The stream is a token** stream (an array of pointers to token structs created on the heap when needed). The last token in the stream is a special End Of Stream token.

My program is segfaulting as the EOS token is being set to a null pointer. After debugging, I find that the function that goes through the symbol table and assigns values was causing the issue. The symbol table is another token**, which contains only pointers to the variables in the stream produced by the scanner.

It originally looked like this:

```
void assignVariables()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < symbolPointerIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("Is %s true or false?", symbols[i]->name);

        char answer = getc(stdin);
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF); //flush the rest of the input

        switch (answer)
        {
            case 't': case 'T': case '1':
                symbols[i]->value = 1;
                break;
            default:
                symbols[i]->value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I changed it to this, which 'fixed' the problem:

```
void assignVariables()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < symbolPointerIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("Is %s true or false?\n", symbols[i]->name);
        symbols[i]->value = i % 2;
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity, I added getc(stdin), which nullified the EOS token again:

```
void assignVariables()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < symbolPointerIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("Is %s true or false?\n", symbols[i]->name);
        symbols[i]->value = i % 2;
        getc(stdin);
    }
}
```

I'm obviously pretty new to manual memory management but I'm completley lost as to how getc(stdin) is nullifying a pointer the for loop doesn't even touch. I've checked that the loop only runs for the variable tokens, and no operators/EOS.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum {VAR, OP, EOS} tokenType;
static char* typeNames[] = {"VAR", "OP", "EOS"}; //debugging purposes

typedef struct 
{
    tokenType type;
    char* name;
    int value;
} token;

void printStream(token** stream)
{
    int i = 0;
    token* last;
    do
    {
        last = stream[i++];
        printf("Type: %s    Name: %s   Value: %d   Location: %p\n", 
            typeNames[last->type], last->type == VAR ? last->name : "Not a var", 
            last->value, last);
    } while (last->type != EOS);
}


#define SYMBOLSCHUNKSIZE 4
static int symbolsRemaining = 0;
static int symbolPointerChunks = 0;
static int symbolPointerIndex = 0;
static token** symbols = NULL;
token* createIdentifier(char name[])
{
    //check if it's already in the table
    int searchPointer;
    for (searchPointer = 0; searchPointer < symbolPointerIndex; searchPointer++)
        if (!strcmp(name, symbols[searchPointer]->name)) 
            return symbols[searchPointer];

    if (!symbolsRemaining)
    {
        if ((symbols = realloc(symbols, (++symbolPointerChunks * SYMBOLSCHUNKSIZE) * sizeof(token*))) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to extend allocated memory for the symbol pointer array!\n");
            free(symbols);
            exit(-1);
        }

        symbolsRemaining = SYMBOLSCHUNKSIZE - 1;
    }

    token* newID = malloc(sizeof(token));
    newID->type = VAR;
    newID->value = -1;
    newID->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1));

    strcpy(newID->name, name);
    newID->name[strlen(name)] = '\0';

    symbols[symbolPointerIndex++] = newID;

    return newID;
}

void assignVariables()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < symbolPointerIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("Is %s true or false?\n", symbols[i]->name);
        symbols[i]->value = i % 2;
        //getc(stdin); /*UNCOMMENTING THIS CAUSES ISSUES*/
    }
}

#define CHUNKLENGTH 8
token** lex()
{
    int chunks = 1;
    int tokensRemaining = CHUNKLENGTH;
    int streamPointer = 0;
    token** stream = malloc(sizeof(token*) * CHUNKLENGTH);

    char c;

    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n')
    {
        if (isspace(c)) continue;

        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            char name[9];
            name[0] = c;

            int nPointer;
            for (nPointer = 1; isalpha(c = getc(stdin)) && nPointer < 8; nPointer++)
                name[nPointer] = c;
            name[nPointer] = '\0';

            //consume remaining characters if the identifier is too long
            while (isalpha(c)) c = getc(stdin);

            //ask the symbol table for a token for this identifier
            stream[streamPointer++] = createIdentifier(name);

            if (c == '\n') break;

            ungetc(c, stdin);
            continue;

        }

        //usually I'd check the different operators, trying to minimise this
        token* new = malloc(sizeof(token));
        new->type = OP;

        stream[streamPointer++] = new;

        if (!--tokensRemaining)
        {
            if ((stream = realloc(stream, (++chunks * CHUNKLENGTH) * sizeof(token*))) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to extend allocated memory for the token stream!\n");
                free(stream);
                exit(-1);
            }
            tokensRemaining = CHUNKLENGTH;
        }

    }

    token* eos = malloc(sizeof(token));
    eos->type = EOS;
    stream[streamPointer] = eos;

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    token** stream = lex();

    printStream(stream); //fine here, even when done twice

    assignVariables();

    printStream(stream); //segfault due to missing EOS

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing the code has changed the symptom, is all.   The problem will have nothing to do with `getc()`.  It will be because of invalid behaviour in parts of code you haven't shown.   For example, one of the `symbols[i]` not pointing to a valid object.    One symptom of undefined behaviour is that changing unoffending code can (appear to) eliminate the symptoms.

Comment: Agreed, I can't see how it's possible that getc() would give me issues. I have however checked that the memory addresses of each symbols[i] are the same as the memory addresses of the variable tokens.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I've added one. It's at http://pastebin.com/qxzPkfBW

Comment: No external code links please. Put the code directly into your question. Regarding your issue, if you are running on Linux or Mac then suggest you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find your problem.

Comment: Done, thanks. I've tried GDB, I'll try using valgrind.

Comment: `stream[streamPointer++] = createIdentifier(name);`. That's in a `while` loop with no `realloc`. So how does it prevent `stream` from being overflowed?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Checking at the start rather than the end of the while loop fixed my issue. I still don't see how that bug caused the issue as the stream was okay until I called getc(). If you want, you can post that as an answer so I can upvote/accept

Comment: @errorc2146 - No, it was not okay until you added `getc`. It just happened that the program didn't crash. That is how it is with `undefined behaviour` - you don't know what will happen. The program may crash or it may even run as if it was okay.